# Auto Increment column when row is updated

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a MySQL table with the structure seen below. The last column represents the number of downloads of a file. Each time a file is accessed, it's UUID changes.

Table Structure:

```
+---------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+
|  dKey   |     file_name      |     file     |  downloads  |
+---------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+
|  UUID   |     file.mp4       |  file alias  |      0      |
|  UUID2  |  another_file.mov  |  file alias  |      3      |
+---------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I was wondering if there is a way to increment the download count if the row is updated. It's not a requirement, I can change it when I change the UUID, I was just wondering if there was a way to do this.

I looked around and couldn't find anything that showed how to do it, or if it couldn't be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

The syntax would look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_downloads
BEFORE UPDATE ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET new.downloads = old.downloads + 1
END;
```

**EDIT**

When creating the trigger, you may need to change the delimiter, like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER increment_downloads
BEFORE UPDATE ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET new.downloads = old.downloads + 1;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

I tested this in MySQL by first inserting a row like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (uuid, downloads) VALUES ('Test', 0);
```

I updated it like so:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET uuid = 'Test1'
WHERE uuid = 'Test';
```

And when I pulled the row, downloads was equal to 1:

[image]

---

NOTE: In a trigger, you cannot set the value of a `new.` column in an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, which is why my answer was edited to use `BEFORE`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution is to create an after update trigger.Within the trigger You can update the count accordingly.

http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_update.php